# NFS server installtion

Tags: centos5

While configuring NFS server error 'Starting NFS services:  exportfs: /etc/exports: 1: bad fsid "fsid=fsid=1"'.

Can you solve this query???????????

Answer (score 1):

Open the file it mentions in the error, look for the text it gives in the error, and fix the problem (you probably don't want "fsid=" twice there).